# Wrong result when replacing with regex

Tags: javascript, string, replace, expression

I'm replacing a sub-string using replace function and regex expression.
However after character escape and replacement, I still have an extra '/' character. I'm not really familiar with regex can someone guide me.

I have implemented the escape character function found here: [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

```
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
```

```
const latexConversions = [
    ["\\cdot", "*"],
    ["\\right\)", ")"],
    ["\\left\(", "("],
    ["\\pi", "pi"],
    ["\\ln\((.*?)\)", "log($1)"],
    ["stdev\((.*?)\)", "std($1)"],
    ["stdevp\((.*?)\)", "std(\[$1\], \"uncorrected\")"],
    ["mean\((.*?)\)", "mean($1)"],
    ["\\sqrt\((.*?)\)", "sqrt($1)"],
    ["\\log\((.*?)\)", "log10($1)"],
    ["\(e\)", "e"],
    ["\\exp\((.*?)\)", "exp($1)"],
    ["round\((.*?)\)", "round($1)"],
    ["npr\((.*?),(.*?)\)", "($1!/($1-$2)!)"],
    ["ncr\((.*?),(.*?)\)", "($1!/($2!($1-$2)!))"],
    ["\\left\|", "abs("],
    ["\\right\|", ")"],
];

RegExp.escape = function (s) {
    var t = s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    return t;
};

mathematicalExpression = "\\sqrt( )"

//Problem is here
mathematicalExpression = mathematicalExpression.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape(latexConversions[8][0]), 'g'), latexConversions[8][1]);

//Works
mathematicalExpression2 = mathematicalExpression.replace(/\\sqrt\((.*?)\)/g, "sqrt($1)"); 

alert("what I got: "+mathematicalExpression); // "\sqrt()"
alert("Supposed to be: "+ mathematicalExpression2); // "sqtr()"
```

I have a live example here: https://jsfiddle.net/nky342h5/2/

Comment: Corrected the typo and the error persists!

Comment: But there cannot be a match, because the two parentheses in `(.*?)` are also escaped by `RegExp.escape`. Just output the result of the call of `RegExp.escape` and you'll see what happened. Just debug. Also, note how one backslash before a `(` in your source string is useless, it just escapes the parenthesis that did not need escaping in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several misconceptions regarding the string literal `"\\sqrt\((.*?)\)"`:

1. This string in raw characters is: `\sqrt((.*?))`. Note how there is no difference between the two opening parentheses: the backslash in the string literal was not very useful. In other words, `"\(" === "("`
2. *Both* opening parentheses will be escaped by `RegExp.escape`
3. Points 1 and 2 are equally true for the closing parentheses, for the dot, the asterisk and the question mark: they will be escaped by `RegExp.escape`.

In short, you have no way to distinguish that a character is intended as a literal or as a regex special symbol -- you are escaping all of them as if they were intended as literal characters.

### The solution:

Since you already are encoding regex specific syntax in your strings (like `(.*?)`), you might as well use regex literals instead of string literals.

In the case you highlighted, instead of this:

```
["\\sqrt\((.*?)\)", "sqrt($1)"]
```

...use  this:

```
[/\\sqrt\((.*?)\)/g, "sqrt($1)"]
```

And let your code do:

```
mathematicalExpression = mathematicalExpression.replace(...latexConversions[8]);
```

### Alternative

If for some reason regex literals are a no-go, then define your own special syntax for `(.*?)`. For instance, use the symbol `µ` to denote that particular regex syntax.

Then your array pair would look like this:

```
["\\sqrt(µ)", "sqrt($1)"],
```

...and code:

```
mathematicalExpression = mathematicalExpression.replace(
    new RegExp(RegExp.escape(latexConversions[8][0]).replace(/µ/g, '(.*?)'), 'g'), 
    latexConversions[8][1]
);
```

Note how here the `(.*?)` is introduced in the string *after* `RegExp.escape` has done its job.

Comment: An array of expressions, brilliant ! `[/\\sqrt\((.*?)\)/g, "sqrt($1)"]` fixed the issue. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

extra \ rather than escaping everything

```
replace     ["\\sqrt\((.*?)\)", "sqrt($1)"],  with     ["\\\\sqrt\((.*?)\)", "sqrt($1)"],

and replace the final replace with 
mathematicalExpression = mathematicalExpression.replace(new RegExp((latexConversions1[8][0]), 'g'), latexConversions1[8][1]);
```